# AVfoundation Camera goes off screen Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on scanning barcode ios App that uses AVFoundation

So i have created a square box with constraint using the interface builder. The square box is all good with the constraints. Perfectly fine.
i have this following code to add the avcapturelayer to the square box.

```
self.captureLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
[self.captureLayer setFrame:self.cameraPreviewView.layer.bounds];
[self.captureLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[self.cameraPreviewView.layer addSublayer:self.captureLayer];
```

the layer follows the leading space from the square box constraint, but not with the trailing. The new added AVlayer goes off the screen(to the right) while the square box itself is all good. What am I missing here?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to set self.captureLayer bounds/position instead of frame ?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening if you are setting the frame in `viewDidLoad`. If so, try doing it in `viewWillAppear:`instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
CGRect bounds=view.layer.bounds;
captureLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
captureLayer.bounds=bounds;
captureLayer.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```

Or

as you are you are using `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` so it will go out of screen , you can use  `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFit` instead.

you need to set `clipToBound=YES;` when using `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` (when using you View )

```
view.clipToBound=YES;
```

and than add Sublayer to view

```
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```